# Python Selenium hierarchical web class extract

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to do search for a specific class and then limit the search to specific found elements in order to keep the hierachical structure in my html page.

My html page looks like this

```
<div1 class = "1">
  <div2 class = "2">
       <div3 class="d">val1</div3>
       <div3 class="d">val2</div3>
  <div2>
<div1>
<div1 class = "1">
  <div2 class = "2">
       <div3 class="d">val3</div3>
       <div3 class="d">val4</div3>
  <div2>
</div1>
```

I would like to have a similar output like this:
{"1": "val1, val2", "2": "val3, val4"}

My code with Python Selenium looks like this:

```
# Extract all elements with class 1
all = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".1")
# return list of length 2

# Search only in first element for class d

class_d = all[0].find_elements_by_css_selector(".2 > d")
len(class_d)

# returns a list of len 4 instead of 2
```

How can I limit the search to a specific DOM element?

Comment: You need to revisit your question/HTML, because as per your expected output _`{"1": "val1, val2", "2": "val3, val4"}`_, `"2"` doesn't have the identical relation with `"val3, val4"` as `"1"` have with `"val1, val2"`

Answer (score 1):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
> selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
> characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
> (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
> by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
> ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
> the identifier “B&W?” may be written as “B&W?” or “B\26 W\3F”.
>
> -W3C Specification

You would have seen in the browser console that even if you write `.1`, Nothing won't show up.

I tried the same with the below HTML and with XPath:

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "1">
  <div class = "2">
       <div class="d">val1</div>
       <div class="d">val2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "1">
  <div class = "2">
       <div class="d">val3</div>
       <div class="d">val4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
driver.get("C:/Users/username/somefolder/Desktop/Automation/example.html")

all = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='1']")
# return list of length 2

# Search only in the first element for class d

class_d = all[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//child::div[@class='2']/child::div")
print(len(class_d))
```

**Output:**

```
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```